# Why is $S$ in SVD a vector instead of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, math-software

I know that when applying SVD on a matrix (m * n) I should have these three outputs:

```
S: m × n diagonal matrix with non negative numbers
U: m × m orthogonal matrix
V: n × n orthogonal matrix
```

but when using R statistical package. I got for S a vector instead of a matrix:

look please:

this is the matrix:
[image]

and after applying the SVD, i got these:
[image]

notice that S (the first result) is a vector of (1 * 6), while it should be from size ( 6 * 6)

what's going on please?

Comment: It is may be giving you just the elements of the main diagonal

Comment: @CarlosMendoza are you saying that this is a 6 * 6 matrix where all the values are one but the diagonal contains the values listed in the picture ?

Comment: so it is, check other example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Example

Comment: @janmarqz in wikipedia they put S as a matrix not a vector (they they don't call it S, but that's just a name)

Comment: It is more compact to just return the diagonal in code. You can always assemble the appropriate matrix if need be. Matlab does the same if you ask for the singular values and do not ask for the singular vectors.

Comment: Have you considered checking the R's documentation (e.g., [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/fullrefman.pdf))? It says clearly 
`d...a vector containing the singular values of x, of length min(n, p).`

Answer (score 2):

The notation

$$S = \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_N)$$

defines the symmetric matrix

$$
S = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
0 & \lambda_2 & \ldots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & \lambda_N\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Other notation than can helps to understand the situation is

$$d = \text{diag}(S)$$

which defines a vector with the elements in the main diagonal of $S$

$$
d =
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1\\
\lambda_2\\
\vdots\\
\lambda_N\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

EDIT: The [svd](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/svd.html) function gives you a vector of length $\text{min}(n,m)$ with the singular values of the matrix. In your case $n=6$ and $m=5$, therefore the length of the vector is $5$. As you said, the matrix $S$ is $6\times 5$, therefore in this case $S$ would have zeros everywhere except at the first $5$ elements in the main diagonal. That is, the last row of $S$ is all zeros. Although the above notation is not being used strictly, it could help to understand why a vector and not a matrix, which was your original question.

EDIT2: I change my wording in my firs edit in response to Mike's comment. $\text{min}(n,m)$ is the length of the vector $p$ that is returned by the svd function, which is the number of singular values that an $n\times m$ matrix can have, and some of them can be zero. I guess that if the rank $r$ of the matrix is less than $\text{min}(n,m)$, the function would return $\text{min}(n,m)-r$ singular values equal to zero in the vector. I could test this maybe later.

EDIT3: Here an example where the rank $r$ of the matrix is $3$ but $\text{min}(4,5) = 4$.

$\hspace{3cm}$ [image]

The svd function returns a vector of lenght $4$, with $3$ non-zero singular values and one singular value equal to $0$.

Comment: then why the S has 5 values instead of 6 ?

Comment: I made an edit.

Comment: The number of non-zero singular values is equal to the rank of the matrix, rather than $\min(n,m)$.

Comment: @MikeMiller I made an edit. Thanks for pointing me this out.

Answer (score 0):

Every matrix 
$$
\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}
$$
has a **singular value decomposition**

$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} &=
  \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} \\
%
 &=
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S}_{\rho\times \rho} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% V* 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
%
 &=
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cccc|cc}
     \sigma_{1} & 0 & \dots &  &   & \dots &  0 \\
     0 & \sigma_{2}  \\
     \vdots && \ddots \\
       & & & \sigma_{\rho} \\\hline
       & & & & 0 & \\
     \vdots &&&&&\ddots \\
     0 & & &   &   &  & 0 \\
  \end{array} \right]
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
  & =
% U
   \left[ \begin{array}{cccccccc}
    \color{blue}{u_{1}} & \dots & \color{blue}{u_{\rho}} & \color{red}{u_{\rho+1}} & \dots & \color{red}{u_{n}}
  \end{array} \right]
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% V
   \left[ \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{v_{1}^{*}} \\ 
    \vdots \\
    \color{blue}{v_{\rho}^{*}} \\
    \color{red}{v_{\rho+1}^{*}} \\
    \vdots \\ 
    \color{red}{v_{n}^{*}}
  \end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$

The $S$ in your output is the list of singular values $\sigma$. The are the diagonal elements of the invertible matrix $\mathbf{S}$.

The $\rho$ singular values are ordered and satisfy 
$$
  \sigma_{1} \ge \sigma_{2} \ge \dots \ sigma_{1} > 0/
$$

---

---

The target matrix has rank $\rho = 5$ as evidenced by the reduction.
$$
\begin{align}
   \left[ \begin{array}{c|c}
     \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{I}_{6}
   \end{array} \right]
 \qquad &\mapsto \qquad
   \left[ \begin{array}{c|c}
     \mathbf{E_{A}} & \mathbf{R}
   \end{array} \right] \\
%
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc|cccccc}
 5 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 3 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 3 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 2 & 5 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
&\mapsto
%
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc|rrrrrr}
 \boxed{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{45}{23} & -\frac{6}{23} & -\frac{21}{23} & -\frac{28}{23} & -\frac{9}{23} & 0 \\
 0 & \boxed{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{65}{23} & \frac{1}{23} & \frac{38}{23} & \frac{43}{23} & \frac{13}{23} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \boxed{1} & 0 & 0 & \frac{245}{23} & -\frac{2}{23} & -\frac{122}{23} & -\frac{178}{23} & -\frac{49}{23} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \boxed{1} & 0 & -\frac{77}{23} & -\frac{2}{23} & \frac{39}{23} & \frac{52}{23} & \frac{20}{23} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \boxed{1} & -\frac{60}{23} & \frac{8}{23} & \frac{28}{23} & \frac{45}{23} & \frac{12}{23} & 0 \\\hline
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{435}{23} & \frac{11}{23} & -\frac{249}{23} & -\frac{286}{23} & -\frac{110}{23} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$

---

The SVD for this matrix is

*Column space*
$$
\mathbf{U} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{llllll}
% r 1
 \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.509682} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.374719} & \color{blue}{-0.163866} & \color{blue}{-0.142365} & \color{blue}{-0.0737315} & \color{red}{\phantom{-}0.739766} \\
% r 2
 \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.173038} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.137867} & \color{blue}{-0.00979447} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.911177} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.346932} & \color{red}{\phantom{-}0.0187067} \\
% r 3
 \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.362913} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.0169967} & \color{blue}{-0.619884} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.134304} & \color{blue}{-0.535164} & \color{red}{-0.423452} \\
% r 4
 \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.309388} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.514438} & \color{blue}{-0.0113491} & \color{blue}{-0.332591} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.540673} & \color{red}{-0.486375} \\
% r 5
 \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.506436} & \color{blue}{-0.0388134} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.753794} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.0615524} & \color{blue}{-0.367462} & \color{red}{-0.187067} \\
% r 6
 \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.475792} & \color{blue}{-0.757718} & \color{blue}{-0.143042} & \color{blue}{-0.130562} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.400559} & \color{red}{\phantom{-}0.0391141} \\
% 
\end{array}
\right]
$$

*Singular values*
$$
\Sigma = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0}
\end{array} \right] 
=
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 12.6517 & . & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 5.77087 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 4.74869 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 2.57851 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.657751 \\\hline
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

*Row space*
$$
\mathbf{V} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{lllll}
 \color{blue}{0.580601} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.407297} & \color{blue}{-0.157745} & \color{blue}{-0.6654} & \color{blue}{-0.17138} \\
% r 2
 \color{blue}{0.397023} & \color{blue}{-0.490966} & \color{blue}{-0.743842} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.198119} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.0936634} \\
% r 3
 \color{blue}{0.200313} & \color{blue}{-0.0529838} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.120244} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.347355} & \color{blue}{-0.906617} \\
% r 4
 \color{blue}{0.428466} & \color{blue}{-0.625199} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.608566} & \color{blue}{-0.189028} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.139496} \\
% r 5
 \color{blue}{0.530629} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.446521} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.192363} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.601336} & \color{blue}{\phantom{-}0.347049} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$